# Is Nagios capable of covering the functionality of Logwatch?

Tags: nagios, logwatch

I have decided to adopt Nagios for our infrastructure. We were going to use Logwatch, but after seeing some of the things in Nagios like log rotation I am wondering if Nagios is capable of sending daily\weekly reports similiar to Logwatch aka replacing Log watch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few addons you can use with Nagios to extend its functionality and therefore customize it to fit your needs.  Check out the [Reporting addons](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Reporting) page of [Nagios Exchange](http://exchange.nagios.org/) for the addons specific to providing more extensive reporting capability.

Specifically, you might want to look at [Nagios Email Reporter](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Reporting/Nagios-Email-Reporter/details).

> This perl script can request an
>   overnight, daily, weekly or monthly
>   report from the Nagios server using
>   the standard CGIs, it then parses the
>   output (formats CSS for Web and Lotus
>   Notes), then emails as an Inline HTML
>   email to a supplied email address.